# How to print only two digits after decimal with System.printf?

Tags: java, string

My problem is that double value converted to string cannot be splitted by dot.

Here you can see my code:

```
String valueOf = String.valueOf(12.34);
System.out.println("valueOf=" + valueOf);

String[] split = valueOf.split(".");
System.out.println("split=" + Arrays.toString(split));
```

The output is:

```
valueOf = 12.34
split = []
```

Why is `split` array empty?

You can try to run it on https://ideone.com/BBL4z2.

Comment: Because `.` is a special character in Regex, you should escape it (`split` accepts a **regex**, not a String).

Comment: Use the following `\\.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape `.` here. you can use `\\.`

```
String[] split = valueOf.split("\\.");
```

Because in `regex` you need to escape `.`